# Posting Formdata on nestjs server

Tags: nestjs

I am trying to make a post request on my nestjs server in a formdata format. I have tried out:

```
@Post()
createUser(
    @Body(new ValidationPipe({transform: true})) createUserDTO:CreateUserDTO,
) {
    console.log("creating new user", createUserDTO)
}
```

but so far what i console.log comes out to:

> creating new user {}

or an empty DTO. Can you kind people on the internet advise me on how to fix my issue? Thanks

Comment: These are transpilation errors. You could try to decrease the typescript version or have to fix the code. Former typescript versions were not entirely type safe, that might be the reason, why the program maybe was once running. But in fact the code seems to be incorrect as mentioned in the given messages.